How to add trusted sites in Phishing detection in Moto secure app
I am using openId for authentication in my android app [using WebView]
Facing issues with login only with Moto Edge 50 pro devices suddenly
After a long research, found that Phishing detection feature inside Moto secure app in Motorola edge 50 pro is blocking authentication callbacks
When i disable Phishing detection feature, everything is working fine
There is no option to add or edit trusted URL's in Moto secure app, Is there any way to whitelist the app url's ?
Have anyone came across this issue, if so any help would be helpful
Thanks in advance
Screenshots below :
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/V0rZLcMt.jpg)
